# JavaFX t̶e̶x̶t̶a̶r̶e̶a̶ CodeArea event on specific character deleted

Tags: javafx, textarea, undo

Something like "onTextDeleted(String deletedText)" or some property, textProperty doesn't help really much. I can do some stuff like saving the caretPosition before something is deleted (backspace,delete or whenever selectedText is overwriten) and inside the textProperty use the currentCaretPosition and do a substring(currentCaretPosition,savedCaretPositionBeforeDelete).contains(";") from the old value or viceversa if the text selection was done backwards.

I mean, that doesn't seem very practical, and that's what im currently doing. I've been looking into the getUndoManager() but theres no access to the undoList(). BTW i'm using RichtextFX from Tomas Mikula.

Answer (score 0):

<s>TextFormatter can handle and control changes of TextInputControl.</s>

This is an approach for components extends JavaFX's TextInputControl.

```
textArea.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {
    if (change.isDeleted() || change.isReplaced()) {
        System.out.println("Text removal: " + change.getControlText().substring(change.getRangeStart(), change.getRangeEnd()));
        System.out.println("Text additional: " + change.getText());
        System.out.println("CaretPosition current: " + change.getControlCaretPosition());
        System.out.println("CaretPosition to: " + change.getCaretPosition());

        // change.setCaretPosition(position);
    }
    return change;
}));
```

See [TextFormatter.Change: API Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html) for detail.

Comment: There's no setTextFormatter() method available for CodeArea, it's my fault for the misleading title.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was a solution for controls extends JavaFX's `TextInputControl`. RichtextFX's `CodeArea` appears to be scratch component.